# Background - IE issue (working with every other browser)

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, background

I have the following page that is working perfectly on every browser but IE.
The issue on IE is the messed up background on the second maincontent/letcol div.
Any idea why it doesn't fit with the rest of the page?

Many thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
<style type="text/css">
p, h1, h2 {
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
body {
    width:960px;
    margin:auto;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    background:#CCC;
    color:#666;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
a, a:visited {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ff8000;
    font-weight:bold
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline
}
#maincontent, #intro {
    clear:left;
    padding-top:20px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    padding:20px;
    display:block
}
#leftcol {
    float:left;
    width:360px;
    padding-right:20px;
    background-color:#ffffff
}
#rightcol {
    float:left;
    width:540px;
    background-color:inherit
}
#strap {
    padding-bottom:46px;
}
.lines {
    float:left;
    padding-right:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    border-right:1px #CCC solid
}
h1 {
    margin-bottom:0;
    font-size: 25px;
}
.lines h2 {
    color:#999;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
    padding-top:0;
    text-align:left
}
.lines h3 {
    color: #999;
    font-size:11px;
    margin-top:0;
    font-weight:normal
}
p {
    margin-top:0;
    padding-top:0;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
p, li {
    line-height:17px;
}
.quoteArea {
    float:right;
    width:375px;
}
.quote {
    color:#ff8000;
    font-style:italic;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:right;
    padding-left: 80px;
}
.infographic {
    background:#ff8000;
    text-align:center;
    padding:20px 10px 30px 10px;
}
h2 {
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:17px;
}
.calltoaction {
    background:#ff8000;
    padding:10px;
    margin-top:20px;
    color:#FFF;
    clear:both;

}
.calltoaction ul, .calltoaction li{ list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0}

.calltoaction li {
    float:left;
    font-size:14px;padding:10px 15px 10px 0; 
}

.logos {
    clear:left;
    float:right;margin:20px;
    display:block
}
.calltoaction a, .calltoaction a:visited{
    color:#FFF
}
.whatwecando {
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    background-color:#e7e7e7;
    padding:10px;
    width:340px;
}
.whatwecando ul {
    padding-left:17px;
    margin-left:0px
}
.whatwecando li {
    margin-left:0;
    list-style:url('page%20build/dotOrange.png') outside;
}
</style>
<title>TITLE</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="intro">
  <h1>header</h1>
  <div id="strap">
    <div class="lines">
      <h2>header2</h2>
      <h3>header3</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="lines">
      <h2>header2</h2>
      <h3>header3</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="lines">
      <h2>header2</h2>
      <h3>header3</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="maincontent">
  <div id="leftcol">
    <p><strong>TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText</strong></p>
    <p><strong>TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText</strong></p>
    <p><strong>TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText</strong></p>
    <p>TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText</p>
    <p>TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText</p>
  </div>
  <div id="rightcol">
    <div class="infographic">
      <h2>header2</h2>
      <img src="test.png" width="515" height="485" alt="Ialt" /> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="whatwecando">
    <h2>header2</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>TextTextTextTextTextTextText</li>
      <li>TextTextTextTextText</li>
      <li>TextTextTextTextTextText</li>
      <li>TextTextTextTextTextText</li>
      <li>TextTextTextTextTextTextText</li>
      <li>TextTextTextTextTextText</li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="quoteArea">
    <div class="quote">
      <p>&quot; TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText &quot;<br />
        <span style="color:#666; font-style:normal">author</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="quote">
      <p>&quot; TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
        &quot;<br />
        <span style="color:#666; font-style:normal">author2</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="quote">
      <p>&quot;TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
        &quot;<br />
        <span style="color:#666; font-style:normal">auhtor3</span></p>
    </div><br clear="all"/>
  <img src="page build/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt="spacer" style="clear:left"/>
  </div>
  <br clear="all"/>
  <img src="page build/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt="spacer" style="clear:left"/>
  <div class="calltoaction">
    <h2 style="text-align:left">header2</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><img src="image.png" width="16" height="16" alt="Valt" align="left" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.url.co.uk</a></li>
      <li><img src="page .png" width="16" height="16" alt="Email us" align="left"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="mailto:mailto.com</a></li>
      <li style="width:150px"><img src="page img.png" width="16" height="16" alt="Phone us" align="left"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;0207 393 7330</li>
    </ul>  <br clear="all"/>
  <img src="page build/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt="spacer" style="clear:left"/>
  </div>
  <img src="page build/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt="spacer" style="clear:left"/>
  <div class="logos"><a href="http://www.logo.com"><img src="paglogo.png" alt="altt" width="173" height="56" border="0" /></a></div>
  <br clear="all"/>
  <img src="build.gif" width="1" height="1" alt="spacer" style="clear:left"/></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check your HTML especially the list items near the end of the html markup you have couple closing tags missed.

Also, some attributes in your code are outdated and not semantic such as `<br clear="all"/>`, you can set most of these formatting via CSS especially you're using it already.

Comment: mmhh, can't see the missing tags. Could you be a bit more specific please?

Comment: the first li `<a href="http://www.url.co.uk</a></li>` you missed the `">` also the `<img src="page .png"` you left a space between the image and the extension